# Origin of the terminology "connected algebra"

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

I was wondering what is the origin of the word "connected" for a connected algebra ?

To be more precise, why is a graded $R$-algebra $A_{\ast}$ with an augmentation $A_{\ast} \to R$ that restricts to an isomorphism $A_0 \stackrel{\cong}{\to} R$ called connected ?

Thanks !

Comment: Maybe because the cohomology ring of a space is connected if and only if the space is? (I hope this is actually the case...)

Comment: That sounds like a pretty reasonable reason!

Comment: You know definitions have been wisely made when it is possible to find arguments merely by the labels affixed to objects.